# How can we balance one-half of an oxygen molecule, or any other diatomic, in a chemical reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

How can we balance oxygen or any other diatomic molecule with a fractional coefficient in a reaction?  I mean, if we can balance oxygen atoms in an odd number what happens to other oxygen atom, and can this sort of reaction even happen?

Comment: The use of fractions is irrelevant, as it's only the ratio that matters. If you don't like fractions you can multiply through by the denominator to get all whole numbers.

Answer (score 11):

Whenever a chemical reaction is written with fractional coefficients, implicitly it's meant to be interpreted as the amount of substance *in moles* of each species that is involved.  So, it's not really one half of an oxygen *molecule* reacting, but *0.5 moles* of $\ce{O2}$ reacting.

bon's comment is spot-on -- if you are trying to think about a reaction written this way on a molecular level, you need to multiply the reaction through by whatever constant eliminates all the fractions.

Comment: Brian you mean in molecular level it is impossible to write reaction in Fraction but if the coefficient numbers mean moles we can use Fraction is that true ? and THANK YOU SO SO MUCH  and please answer my question in Easy English because i am not native speaker

Comment: @Yasser Yes, that's exactly right. On the molecular level it makes little sense to write in fractions, but on the 'moles level' it's fine.

Comment: Please note that the proper term for "number of moles" is [amount of substance](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00297.html). The former would be the same as referring to the mass as "number of kilograms".

Comment: @Martin-マーチン How would you rewrite? For the life of me I can't concisely frame how to express that the coefficients are to be multiplied into a one-mole quantity of each species.

Comment: Simply substitute number of moles with amount of substance (in moles of you really need to add that).

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Hm, indeed, that sounds okay to me. But one wouldn't say "amount of eggs in dozens," right?  I guess 'eggs' is a countable thing, though, while 'substance' as a quantity measure is an uncountable thing... which is probably where the difference comes in.

Comment: I actually would say that, or simply number of eggs in dozens, but we're drifting into linguistics here. In this very case, the quantity has a name, the unit has a name, these should be used at the appropriate places, no matter if it were different with other things.

Comment: @hBy2Py IUPAC also recommends *enplethy* for international usage. I have been trying to use it as of late due to brevity and to sound posh.

Comment: I see amount of substance as a definition that stress our current understanding. In particular it stresses the nature of matter as substance  , thus giving a physical and chemical identity and assume that matter to be a collection of things.  To date we do not have dark matter as substance. I found amount of matter really distinct from other quantities. It is just a consideration. It has little to do with the specific question